# Mixing .loc and .iloc slicing to select first n rows of index sublevels

Tags: pandas

[image]

I have a multilevel index.  I'd like to select the first two rows of each style (example highlighted in yellow).  Sort of an `.iloc[:, :2]` of the DataFrame, except that doesn't work.

Another variation would be to `.loc` to select only certain `style` in the top level of the index, and then `.iloc[:n]` to select the first `n` rows of the inner `bureau` level.   example, *"first 2 rows of 'fox' and 'bear' styles.*

I'm able to use `IndexSlice` when I want to slice everythign based on labels, but I cannot find an equivalent for location-based based slicing, or mixing label- and location- based slicing.

```
import numpy as np
tuples = [
    ('fox', 'anton1'),
    ('fox', 'anton2'),
    ('fox', 'anton3'),
    ('fox', 'anton4'),
    ('bat', 'girv2'),
    ('bat', 'girv3'),
    ('bat', 'girv4'),
    ('bat', 'girv5'),
    ('bear', 'kalg1'),
    ('bear', 'kalg2'),
    ('bear', 'kalg3'),
    ('bear', 'kalg4'),
]
np.random.seed(1)
data = np.random.rand(12,1)
mix = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=('style', 'bureau'))

df = pd.DataFrame(index=mix, data=data, columns=['foo'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.GroupBy.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df.groupby(level='style').head(2)
```

Here is another way:

```
df.groupby(level='style').apply(lambda d: d.iloc[2:4]).droplevel(0)
```

Comment: I guess that works, but using `.head()` loses the flexibility of `.iloc[q:x]` arbitrary row selection,  and it also doesn't allow to do a label-like slice on the  `style` level.

Comment: @user3556757 I provided an alternative for arbitrary slicing